# How to check size of array in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Array .for example:

```js
CaptionList = [
        { caption: "John" },
        { caption: "Jack" },
        { caption: "Jounior" }
    ];
```

I was created an Tag Input Control and fill it by CaptionList.like this,

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <div id="divItems" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height: 50px;" class="form-control">

        <span  ng-repeat="item in CaptionList " class="item">
           <span><i id="imgDelete" class="fa fa-remove"  ng-click="remove($index)"></i>&nbsp; {{item.caption}} </span>
        </span>
        
    </div>

</div>
```

Now,I want check if lenght of CaptionList is less than 1 and more than 3 it shows an error message . any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-if="CaptionList.length < 1 || CaptionList.length > 3">Error Message</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.ok ,I want if condition is incorrect show error message and prevent to binding array to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-show="CaptionList.length < 1 || CaptionList.length > 3 " >
   Error Msg
</div>
```

I rather prefer to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, because `ng-if` creates a child scope while `ng-show` does not. That may produce unexpected results.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think `ng-show` and `ng-if` need to be evaluated on a case by case basis instead of just preferring one over the other. For instance, `ng-show/ng-hide` have their own issues when used to show or hide rows in a striped table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array name .length to determine the length.
i.e

```
CaptionList.length
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="CaptionList.length < 1 || CaptionList.length > 3">Error Message</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be "less than 1 OR more than 3", you can not have a number less than 1 and more than 3, in that case all responses are correct.

As alternative you can use ng-show in stead of ng-if

```
<div ng-show="CaptionList.length < 1 || CaptionList.length > 3">Not Error Message</div>
```